# How to display products about to expire

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is my code

```
$now = date('Y-m-d');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE date_diff(`expiry`, '$now') BETWEEN 0 AND 14";
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
return $query->result_array();
```

And here is a sample database

```
id = 1
name = checkers 400g
costprice = 350
price = 400
qty = 100
availability = 1
expiry = 2019-05-02
```

I keep getting error and I have been working on it since early morning. I have about 544 record in my database, just picked out 1 as sample as shown above. Please help

Comment: Which error did you get? What do you look for with 'BETWEEN 0 AND 14'. PLease explain.

Comment: If the date comes from PHP, it is considered a string and you should use ``date_diff(`expiry`, '$now')`` but my guess is you also get a syntax error because there's no space between `*` and `FROM`.

Comment: I'm displaying the result on a data table..... I keep getting error for the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming that expiry is a valid date/datetime column You could try

```
$sql = "SELECT *
        FROM products 
        WHERE `expiry` BETWEEN DATE(NOW()) DATE_ADD((date(NOW()),   INTERVAL 14 DAY)";
```